# Save current pose snapshot of a skeletal mesh as a new animation sequence asset from blueprint

Tags: unreal-4, skeletal-animation, blueprints

What I'm trying to do is create a Blueprint Utility tool that lets me create an Animation Sequence asset to save the current Pose Snapshot of a skeletal mesh.

I see there's Create Asset node from Asset Tools Actor but I have no clue on how to create the factory to make it (same with Create Asset with Dialog).

I'm currently trying by using the LE Extended Standard Library that provides the Engine of many Factory blueprints, but whenever I try to save it, the engine crashes and I cannot investigate the error. A possible issue could be linked to the **calling context**? I'm not sure about that one and I didn't find an answer on UE4 forums.

[image: current state]

What I would like to achieve is to create an asset like this:

[image: asset from content browser]

[image: Animation Sequence asset I want to create]

by providing the Pose Snapshot (collection of bones and transforms) of the selected actor:

[image: in game actor selected]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intent is to save a Snapshot Pose to use it later, a way to do it, that worked for me, is saving it in a proper slot and load it whenever needed (in my case at begin play).
The blueprint utility would look like this:

[image: saving pose of selected actors]

Loading at begin play and setting the pose as starting pose:

[image: loading pose]

Where "Load Pose" handles the starting Skeletal Pose and the Anim instance sets it as current:

[image: animator handling pose]